# Uploaded images are corrupted in all browsers

Tags: browser, ftp, image-uploading

I uploaded some images via FTP and it seems that the images are not shown properly.

[image]

1: Checked in the browers: Chrome, IE and Firefox.

2: Did upload with Dreamweaver and Filezilla

3: Did upload on different domains

4: Checked also via 3G, same result

5: Ask someone else to check and has same result.

6: Did upload different images (.jpg and .png)

7: When i view the image in my browser **local** i see the image correct.

Has anyone i idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are using a binary mode transfer, not text/ascii.

Comment: I set in FileZilla Binary, but still the same result...

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!!!

I am having exactly the same problem SINCE YESTERDAY!!!!

Amemov, the problem is that the file is uploaded corrupted, at least in my case. It has he same size, but the first several KBs are repeated. Crazy!!!

Tested several ftp clients, all the same result. I also tested with a 3G connection via tethering, and same thing. But the server is fine for sure, my colleagues can perfectly upload to it.

The problem was a documented bug in AVG. You need to:

1. Disable the AVG Self Protection (AVG -> F8 -> AVG Self Protection -> uncheck "Enable AVG Self Protection" -> OK)
2. Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers

   - Show hidden files and folders if you can't see this folder
3. Replace the relevant driver on the system

   - 32bit (avgwfpx.sys) -
     https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13011391/AV-6987/avgwfpx.zip
   - 64bit (avgwfpa.sys) -
     https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13011391/AV-6987/avgwfpa.zip
4. Restart your computer and try it.

It worked for me!

Comment: By the way amemov, do you use AVG?